# Unset with embedded forms

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have in my Form class:

```
public function configure()
{
        $emb = $this->getEmbeddedForms();
        foreach($emb as $key => $form)
        {
             unset($form['backup']);
        }
}
```

But this not working - not unset.
In $emb i have:

```
oneForm
twoForm
```

In oneForm and twoForm i have widget **backup**. I want unset this with getEmbeddedForms. I can't unset this in oneForm.class and twoForm.class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-embed your form after the `unset`.

```
public function configure()
{
  $emb = $this->getEmbeddedForms();

  foreach($emb as $key => $form)
  {
    unset($form['backup']);

    // re-embed the current form (it will override the previous one)
    $this->embedForm($key, $form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No wonder at all. You assign the content of `$this->getEmbeddedForms()` the local variable `$emb` ;-))... Think about it.

So:

```
<?php
// ...

public function configure() {
 foreach($this->getEmbeddedForms() as $key => &$form) {
  unset($form['backup']);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: now i have error "Fatal error: Cannot create references to elements of a temporary array expression in "

Comment: well... my mistake. ``$this->getEmbeddedForms()`` is dynamic content and not content which can be to (e.g. saved in a variable)...

Comment: @MaxKoovert you need to update the object with the method ``updateObject`` which overrides the default from sfFormDoctrine. Take a look at http://itsmajax.com/2011/01/29/6-things-to-know-about-embedded-forms-in-symfony/ - number 6.